# How to join multiple Apollo queries in the state with React?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm new with React and Apollo applied to MongoDB and I have the following problem:

I have a table where I have (ID - ID_A - ID_B), I made a query for this one and returns me an array. After that, I have to ask in another table for each component in the Array the match with ID_A.

So I Made:

```js
{this.props.firstGet.map((data, index) => {
const id = data.ID_A;
return (
<Query key={this.props.firstGet.id} query={QUERY} variables={{ id }}>
   {({ loading, error, data }) => {
   if (loading) return 'Loading...';
   if (error) return `Error ${error.message}`;
   this.test = this.test.concat({...data.getStartup, ...this.state.applicants[index]});
   return(this.test.length === this.props.getApplicants.length ? 
   <LastTable startups={this.test}></LastTable>
   : '')
   }
   }
</Query>
);
```

Which one is the best practice for my problem? 
I need the first array with a composite for each object with the answer of the second table.
Is there a way to do it directly into the main state without using LastTable for example?

---

How I solve it:
1)Adding in MainTable MongoDB schema:

```
ID_A: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Table1'
}
```

2)In graphQl shcema: ID_A : Table1Object

3)Adding .populate('ID_A') in resolver

I will try now inserting a new one, maybe I have problems but if with the ID in that MainTable ID_A field the connection works great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be handled on graphql server side. You just need to request for those dependent fields to be resolved and returned from server side.

Just for example -

**1.Create schema with fields and sub fields**
   e.g

```
 type Person {
 id: ID!
 cars: [Car]
}

type Car {
  id:ID!
  ownerId: Int!
  model: String
}
```

**2.You need to write nested resolvers on server side**

**Person resolver:**

```
import Query from './query';
import Mutation from './mutation';

export default {
  Query,       //<----- person query resolver 
  Mutation,    //<----- person mutation resolver if any
  Person: { .  //<----- Nested fields resolver on Person
   cars: (parent, args, { dataSources }) => {
      const { id: ownerId } = parent;
      // return from db cars owned by person
      return dataSources.carAPI.getCarsByOwnerId(ownerId);
    },
  },
};
```

I am using [dataSource](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/data-sources.html) here but you can use directly resolve from database.

**3.Query on client side**

```
 export const GET_PERSON_WITH_CARS = gql`
  query getPersonWithCars($id: ID!) {
   person(id: $id) {
      id
      cars {
        id,
        ownerId,
        model,
     }
  }
`
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Ty so much it works! Last question if i had an array of persons ID to query, I have to do it one by one with .map or there is some way to bulk querys??

Comment: you can use dataloader to batch the queries in one go

Comment: i will edit my answer how i solve it TY btw and if u have any comment about my solution just tell me :)